# Sign in via Twitter (iOS)

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, access-token

I am developing an iOS app and want to implement native sign in via Twitter. I am using an example I found here that includes 2 steps, request token and access token. For the second  step I use my twitter ACAccount (account.framework) and my app consumer_key and consumer_secret, and finally obtain an oath_token and oath_token_secret.
The problem is that when I try to fetch data with that token in my app API I get invalid token.

I think a step might be missing here or something. I look at every post related to sign in via Twitter and couldn't solve this...

Thanks everyone

This is the example I based my code

https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample

I did almost everything the same, I am using ARC

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: any especial part of it?

Comment: I would recommend using Parse's SDK for authenticating through Twitter. It may make your life easier. There's other options that are similar to Parse.